# How to type the Components.inputs array in angular

Tags: angular

I noticed that in angular you can define inputs inside the @component decorator

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-component',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
   inputs: ['first', 'last', 'middle']
})
export class ...
```

But how can one now type the inputs, which you simply can do with @Input

```
@Input() first: string;
```

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
inputs: ['name', 'id: number'],
```

This is a string array by default.
Now, create your property in class
as

`id: number`  (without @Input)

Comment: thanks a lot, thats it. But your example is incorrect. In that `inputs` array you don't define a type, but an alias only, so it will look like this `inputs: ['name', 'id: account-id']`